# Adjust the power of laser diode on both CW and pulsed mode

Tags: current-limiting, constant-current, led-driver, laser-diode, laser-driver

I am working on my graduation project to build a laser unit, i am supposed to control the power of laser diode when operating in pulsed mode and continuous mode.
firstly, i had the pulses from "Arduino UNO" and connected it to a FET then i have a pulsed laser diode.
secondly, i implemented a current constant driver which include a comparator "OP-AMP" , curent sensing resistor and FET, then i can control the current of laser diode butt it is not pulsed.
The question here is how can i make an accurate constant current driver controlling the laser diode by digitally (by Arduino) with the ability to work in CW or pulsed mode.

Comment: Show the schematics of your circuits, and specify the components you're using.

Comment: Also, you need to specify the minimum pulse width you need to control and your target for the accuracy of your "accurate constant current driver".

Answer (score 1):

Mosfets are an answer. They do make great current sources and scaling is by size. To be honest I don't know how fast you need to pulse this, but I'm going to give you a part that is both a CC driver and a PWM. You really don't want to make that circuit discretely. CAT4101 from OnSemi. Use a make-before-break digi-pot to change the constant current bias and use pwm for... pwm!